# Leaflet getting slow when there are huge amount of custom markers(1k-10k)

Tags: javascript, android, leaflet

I'm using leaflet to show a floor plane. I have to add markers on the floor. There are two types of shape of the marker, circle and rectangle. when marker amount cross 1k, map rendering became slow and performance also.All these things I'm doing in android webview. I need help to optimize this process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practices for handling thousands of markers with Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795319/best-practices-for-handling-thousands-of-markers-with-leaflet)

Answer (score 1):

I think that is totally normal with that huge amount of markers. A common way is to use Marker Clustering. This way your huge amount of markers gets grouped into a smaller amount while still showing the needed informations to the user.

Take a look at this clustering plugin for Leaflet: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use the cluster. Is there any way of optimizing

Comment: Why don't you want to use a cluster? The only other way is to lower the amount of markers.

Comment: It's gonna be either clustering (https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering), rasterizing ahead of time, using a heatmap or binning, or using something exotic such as Leaflet.GLMarkers. Having lots of standard markers will slow things down no matter what.